# JButton twice setText to JLabel after JPanel revalidate()

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, duplicates, cardlayout

When I click button I want to add one button to panel, which I did, but my program doesn't work like before. This is my program before:

[image]

South panel with pink buttons is cardlayout panel. When I click gray buttons on east, card panels changed. When I click pink button, this happened:

[image]

One pink button setText to one label. After I add one button to cardpanel "TOPLI NAPICI" this happened:

[image]

As you can see, one button "moka" add to panel,which I want, but when I click one button, it setText twice, only new button (in this case "MOKA") setText once. This happened also with other panels in cardpanel:

[image]

this is part of my code when I click button to add new button

```
    if (enter == JOptionPane.OK_OPTION) {
    try{
    Double price1=Double.parseDouble(priceField.getText());

    String name1= productField.getText();


        Product name = new Product(name1, price1);
        Application .manu.add(name);


        if (field.getSelectedItem().equals("TOPLI  NAPICI")){

            for(Controller c:Controller) {
            c.tnp.add(new JButton(name1));//c is panel , holds all panels

         c.tn.revalidate();//c.tn is panel which is changed( adding one button), cardpanel
         c.removeAll();
         c.panels();//create all panels which is removed
             c.revalidate();


    System.out.print( c.tnp.size());//tnp is a list with buttons, shows that add one more button, that is correct

        }
```

Like it duplicate panels, or when I `click button` it clicked twice. Is it possible? And although I changed only one panel in cardlayout ("TOPLI NAPICI"),it changed in all panels in cardlayout ("SOKOVI" and "ALKOHOL")
What is wrong?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: what is the event which you are acting upon? If it is, indeed, related to the amount of times you register the click, then I suggest using the mouseUp event.

Comment: I think your GUI should be totally redesigned. Instead of this GUI which causes a lot of problems you could: Use `JTabbedPane` (set on SOUTH) with 3 tabs and set `JTable` (for every type of drink) in each tab. Each `JTable` would contain list of articles. Then you could add some button so you can add articles to your bill. Also, one `JTable` can replace all those `JLabel`s and `JComboBox`es. Btw, how do think to print a report?

Comment: You are right. When I start with this, I had idea, but no expirience. Can I set table empty and fill it by click a button. Can my program look the same with table instead of labels, comboboxes....?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- no idea whats LayoutManager is used, nothing talking about CardLayout, for better help sooner post an SSCCE, short, runnable, compilable, just about JPanel with CardLayout and one JButton for code posted here,
- images posted here without code not helped
- CardLayout by default never required call for `revalidate() & repaint()`, all those notifiers are implemented in API by default
- this isn't proper way

.

```
c.tn.revalidate();//c.tn is panel which is changed( adding one button), cardpanel
c.removeAll();
c.panels();//create all panels which is removed
c.revalidate();
```

- apply all changes to already visible GUI (remove, add, modify, relayout), then last two code lines should be `revalidate() & repaint()`, for 1st. container where are changes done, or if there are changed a few containers, then to call their 1.st joined container
- up to Java7 is required to use `validate() & repaint()` for `JFrame`, `JDialog`, `JWindow`, in the Java7 is implemented `revalidate()` for `Top Level Containers` too,, the same as for `JPanel` (for example)